# Fix for PHP Warning – Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Tags: php, curl

getting error on shared hosting. working fine on local host and VPS with digital ocean. the error is:

```
Warning: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set in
/var/www/vhosts/qbf.ie/subdomains/projects/httpdocs/smartquotes/wp-
content/themes/smartquotes/form/functions.php on line 59
ERROR: cURL response is empty!
```

my code which is throwing error in functions.php

```
function send_xml_phi($xml) {
$url = 'http://www.xxx.ie/interface_phi.php';
$ch = curl_init();

if(!$ch) {
    die('ERROR: cURL initialization failed!');
}

$redirects = 0;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "xml=".urlencode($xml));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$xml_result=curl_exec_follow($ch,$redirects);
curl_close($ch);

if(!$xml_result) {
    die('ERROR: cURL response is empty!');
}

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_result, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
return $array['Outputs'];
```

}

here is the result.php code foreach loop:

```
foreach($output['Quotes']['Type']['Company'] as $key => $company) {
        if($company['SLevel'] != '-' && $company['SLevel'] < $min) {
            $min = $company['SLevel'];
            $min_key = $key;
        }

        if($company['SMortgage'] != '-' && $company['SMortgage'] < $min) {
            $min = $company['SMortgage'];
            $min_key = $key;
        }
    }

    if($min_key > -1) {
        $text .= '<strong>Cheapest quote:</strong> '.$min.' EUR';
        $text .= ' ('.$output['Quotes']['Type']['Company'][$min_key]['Name'].')<br />';
    }
```

is there some workaround ?

Comment: where is the code where you are using foreach loop

Comment: Have you tried removing the "CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION" option?

Comment: updated. please check the code

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION may have implicit a security issue, and the php.ini security directive *open_basedir* is preventing CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to be used. So you can choose between using cURL without CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION or unsetting *open_basedir* in your php.ini config file.